# BlockRAM location constraints (Xilinx)

Tags: fpga, xilinx, constraints

I have a VHDL module in which several block RAMs are inferred. Now I would like to place these block RAMs into a certain region of my FPGA (close to some IO pins).
How do I do this using Xilinx constraints (UCF file)? Can I group the block RAMs and define a single LOC constraint for the group or do I have to constrain every block RAM individually?

The main hurdle to me is that the number of block RAMs depends on a generic, which is why using one individual constraint for each block RAM seems not possible.

EDIT: The reason I am trying this approach is that my timing constraints can not be met. The timing errors are all related to the block RAMs of one module. Looking at the PAR result I can see that the critical block RAMs are scattered across the center of the FPGA, instead of being placed close to the relevant IO pins. Therefore I want to try to guide PAR into the direction where I think the block RAMs should be placed. The timing results should then tell me if my advice to PAR was helpful or not.

Comment: Search for "Death of the RLOC" - I remember (a while ago) seeing it showed how to embed the LOC constraints as attributes in the VHDL code, and generate them from `for ... generate` statements controlled by that generic.

Comment: Before locking down placement, do you *have* to do it?  Can you add a timing constraint which will the placer will use to push the BRAMs closer to the pins for example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, so after some try and error, here is how I managed to do it:

First an *AREA_GROUP* which spans the part of the design which shall be constrained must be declared (in the projects UCF file).

```
INST "my_module/*" AREA_GROUP="pblock_my_module";
```

This creates an *AREA_GROUP* containing everything in the design hierarchy "below" *my_module*. 
Now a range for the block RAMs within this *AREA_GROUP* can be defined.

```
AREA_GROUP "pblock_my_module" RANGE=RAMB8_X0Y0:RAMB8_X4Y12;
```

The values for the range can be obtained from the vendors floorplanning tools (e.g. Xilinx ISE FPGA Editor). In the example above, all block RAMs (either inferred or instantiated) within *my_module* will be placed in the lower left corner of the FPGA. Since there are much more block RAMs available in that region (*RANGE=RAMB8_X0Y0:RAMB8_X4Y12*) than are required, this is no "hard" placement of the block RAMs, like achieved by the *LOC* constraint, but more flexible.

For details see http://www.xilinx.com/support/documentation/sw_manuals/xilinx12_1/Floorplanning_Methodology_Guide.pdf